# sort words in sequence order in which they were saved

Tags: python-3.x

how to sort words in sequence order in which they were saved in text file, just add new line from below and save same sequence after remove same words. if I add one by one words

```
word A 
word B 
word C 
word D 
word E
```

my result looks like this

```
1. word B
2. word E
3. word C
4. word D
5. word A
```

first was last one, second was first etc

so no order...

only thing I have here is sorting to keep only unique words,

on this:

```
print ('Write word : ')

text = input ('')

data = open ('D:\path\file.txt', 'a')         #Add new word to new line
data.write (text)
data.write('\n')

with open('D:\path\file.txt', 'r') as lines:
    lines_set = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip() not in lines_set:  # Keep only unique words
            lines_set.append(line.strip())


data.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines_set = {line.strip() for line in lines}
```

This is creating a set object for you, and sets do not have any order.
I'd use a list for this task to preserve the order they are added:

```
with open('D:\path\file.txt', 'r') as lines:   
    lines_set = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip() not in lines_set:  # Keep only unique words
            lines_set.append(line.strip())
```

Lines need to be iterated through the long way like this so that only the unique words can be kept.

Comment: There is a frozenset object, but that's just an immutable set and still doesn't remember order

Comment: thank you for your support, now order is good, but same words in list 

`word 1  
word 2 
word 3  
word 5 
word 1 < 
word 6 
word 7 
word 3 <`

I changed the code at the top as I used it, something is wrong?

Comment: I've tested the code with a list of words, including duplicates, and it is working as expected for me, so I don't think the problem is there. Why does your output have '<' symbols? Are the words exactly the same? You might want to do line.strip().lower()  It's at a point now where the debugging requires more than just the code.

Comment: nothing I'll just put this < as arrow by hand to show repeat

I've tried 

`with open('D:\path\file.txt', 'r') as lines:   
    lines_set = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip().lower() not in lines_set:  
            lines_set.append(line.strip().lower())`

result 

`word 1 
word 2 
word 3 
word 4 
word 1 
word 1 
word 1 
word 1` 

maybe because I'm on window... ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is a good idea to update your question if it changed. Most people do not read all comments under the answers to find your problem.

**Now to your question:**

It is often a good idea to analyse the code line by line.

```
import random                               # In this code snippet it is not used?

print ('Write word : ')                     # printing something

text = input ('')                           # get some input -> text

data = open ('D:\path\file.txt', 'a')       #open new file (appending)
data.write (text)                           # write user input at file ending
data.write('\n')                            # write line break at file ending
```

Wait! You want only append a line if it not exists already...

So let us include a test for that

```
print ('Write word : ')

text = input('')
data = open ('file.txt', 'a')         #Add new word to new line

with open('file.txt', 'r') as lines:
    if text.strip() not in map(str.strip, lines):  # Keep only unique words
        data.write(text)
        data.write('\n')

data.close()
```

That will check if the line already exists. Maybe the map function is a little bit confusing, but it only applies the function strip to all lines in the file to get rid of extra space and new line characters.

Now it should work :)

Comment: yes it works very good but how to do it not through the text input? because I have just lists too, without any input,  so would be better somehow sort  list itself directly

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. What do you want to archive and is not solved yet? There are many ways to improve the code above, but I think it is a good idea to use your code as basis, so you can see your mistake easily. Are you worried about performance or is there an other problem?